# render_to_response always pass a variable

Tags: django, django-context

I'm finding myself always passing a 'user' variable to every call to `render_to_response`

A lot of my renders looks like this

```
return render_to_response('some/template', {'my':context,'user':user})
```

Is there a way to automatically send this 'user' variable without manually adding it to the context each time a method is called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, read [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1). Then:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this with Context Processors: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1

In fact if you include DJANGO.CORE.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.AUTH in your context processors then the user is added to every request object.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-auth

You will need to use `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` as others have mentioned to use the Context Processors.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [`render_to`](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home), which is part of django-annoying - which allows you to do things like this:

```
@render_to('template.html')
def foo(request):          
    bar = Bar.object.all()  
    return {'bar': bar}     

# equals to 
def foo(request):
    bar = Bar.object.all()  
    return render_to_response('template.html', 
                              {'bar': bar},    
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You could write a similar decorator (e.g. `render_with_user_to`) that wraps that up with you.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitry is right, but you can further simplify this by using [direct_to_template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) generic view as regular function. Source code for it is [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/simple.py).

There is also nice add-on, `django-annoying`, that provides [render_to](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/src/tip/annoying/decorators.py) decorator doing similar thing but without the need for explicit template rendering.